# Angular controller not register to module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, directive

I am still new on angularjs and have a question: How does the controller still know which module it registerred to on code snippet below (found on the Angular official document):
JS

```
 angular.module('App', []);
    function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.val = 1234.56789;
    }
```

---

Html something like:

```
<html ng-app="App">
<body>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
 ........
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect there is something to do with bootstrap time and $scope available globally???

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a controller in a module, call the `controller` method on the module:

```
var module = angular.module('App', []);

module.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.val = 1234.56789;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Josheph, that is what we've already done in our project. But supprising ly this code snippet WORKS and there are a lot in Angular Official Documentation without further explanation. Here is an example:http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:number. You can see its plnkr

Comment: it works because it defines a simple controller in a global window context... but in a real world, I suppose you can't find an application which is this simple